# How to "un-fix" Sharepoint page background?

Tags: 2010, branding

I’m making a Sharepoint blog site. Instead of using the default fluid layout, I’ve altered the master page to create a fixed width site at 1000px.

Here's my issue: The page background is currently fixed, which seems to be Sharepoint’s default. I would like for it to scroll. Unfortunately, I can’t locate the particular style or tag is that’s making it fixed. Can’t find it in the master page, can’t find it in coreV4.css.

I’ve attached a 2nd stylesheet to the site to handle most of my customizations. I’ve tried adding the style “background-attachment: scroll!important” to the body tag within that stylesheet, but it has no effect.

How can I get the durned background to scroll? It seems like it should be simple to do, so hopefully I'm just missing something easy, which would not be surprising. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much!

Oh, forgot to mention - it's Sharepoint 2010. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You used the right CSS property. I'm just curious how you added your stylesheet. Normally, you should be able to add an override style sheet through the site collection's Site Settings under 'Look and Feel', 'Master Page'. There you can specify an alternate CSS. And in that CSS file specify, styles for elements, classes and ids used by SP2010. If you did it through that, you would not even need to add '!important' in most cases.

As for the Sharepoint class or id to look for, try these:

- #s4-bodyContainer (excludes the scroll bar)
- #s4-titlerow
- #s4-mainarea

I have no access to a default install of SP2010, but our site has background images on the last two elements I listed above. Both are contained in the first element.

Comment: Just in addition, the alternate CSS applies to the whole site collection.

Comment: Hi Frank - I did add the stylesheet in the Master Page area under Site Settings. The background is applied to the body tag via this stylesheet. The #s4-bodyContainer is what I'm constraining to 1000px (which I did in the stylesheet and not the master page, so my initial question is wrong about that part). Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: So are you saying you still cannot find the style that adds the background image? You can use developer tools in FireFox to check if you are finding it difficult to check your coreV4.css.